# How do I successfully wrap my text in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, word-wrap

I am working in Wordpress but am new to PHP. I built a very very simple page using HTML and CSS. It consists of one image to the left and three lines of informational text that are suppose to wrap on the right side. It works and looks perfect before I loaded it to Wordpress and now it is not wrapping.

What am I missing?? Below is the fiddle.

```css
.ciao {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ciaolist {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600X1067" alt="" class="ciao" style="width:55%">
  <ul class="ciaolist">
    <li>contact@website.com</li>
    <br>
    <li>+1 234 567 8900</li>
    <br>
    <li>united states, us</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected look?

Comment: did you check that css attached properly

Comment: @PYYick Hi, I updated my original question with a link.

Comment: @bhv double and triple checked!

Comment: What does it actually looks now?

Comment: The text sits directly under the image and against the left side of the page

Comment: btw ur fiddle has <ui> it should be <ul>

Comment: for `div` element add `display: flex` and adjust image height and other styles..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mvgct0xb/   -  and use media queries to adjust the image width and height or use aspect ratio

Comment: Kayla, are you sure there's no other stylesheet that overrides your CSS code?

Comment: @TripleDeal Hi, yes I am sure. I only have one stylesheet and the CSS I have included above is at the very bottom of my sheet. Is there a line of code that would override a wrap?

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this;

```css
.post-container {
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  overflow: auto
}

.post-thumb img {
  float: left;
}

.ciaolist {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ciao {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-container">
  <div class="post-thumb"><img class="ciao" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600X1067" width="55%" /></div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <ul class="ciaolist">
      <li>contact@website.com</li>
      <br>
      <li>+1 234 567 8900</li>
      <br>
      <li>united states, us</li>
      <br>
      <br>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once I copy and paste the HTML into my wordpress page and the CSS into my stylesheet, it  does the same thing - the text moves directly under the image.